# Why does 'as' work when '=' does not in ngFor?

Tags: html, angular

```
<tr *ngFor = "let item of list; let i = index;">
```

The above code gives error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. td [ngModelGroup]="j" #temp="ngModelGroup"

But the below code runs fine

```
<tr *ngFor = "let item of list; let i as index;">
```

What is the difference in using `i = index` and `i as index`.Previously I was using `i = index` and it was working fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you reproduce it on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `let` before the `i`...

That happens because Angular is searching for the `i` variable in your component logic (the .ts file). And it doesn't find it, so by adding `let` behind the variable, Angular knows that this is not a variable in the component logic but inside the view that should be created.

Here you can find more information about that:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: Sorry,I have added let behind the variable

Comment: Weird question, are you adding the `"` ? ...Like this:
`<tr *ngFor ="let item of list; let i = index">`

Comment: Then you should show that in your question code.

Comment: Yeah I was in a hurry therby making a mistake

Comment: You should share the code and not just a small piece of it then, that issue you're showing is NOT related to the *ngFor itself, it is because another assign is not being working properly, and then, the *ngFor is not detecting the index because it can't be created. The other is a reference, so that doesn't drop an error, you're passing a reference from" undefined/null/whatever" to i

Answer (score 0):

You lack of the double quote sign.
Try this with 3 case below to better understand:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
  <td>{{i}}/{{item}}</td>
</tr>
<p>In this case variable i is a index of list, begin from 0.</p>
<hr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of list1; let j as index">
  <td>{{j}}/{{item}}</td>
</tr>
<p>In this case variable j is a value of index in list.</p>
<hr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of list1; index as k">
  <td>{{k}}/{{item}}</td>
</tr>
<p>In this case variable k is a index of list.</p>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zldcpt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

`let i = index` is not proper Angular syntax anymore. Starting with Angular 5 (IIRC) it became `let i as index`. Did you upgrade Angular recently?

You can check the documentation to verify: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf